# ASP.NET Javascript Hide/Show Read More for Long Text

Tags: javascript, asp.net

So at the moment I have a literal to which I assign a value to from database. I.e an Introduction to a programme.

What I am looking to do is i.e if the text is larger than 100 Characters, to only display the first 100 Characters and then display a javascript link "Read More" which when clicked displays the rest of the content.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS elipses is one quick easy solution:

```
span.ellipsis {
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

The other in .NET would be something like:

```
string YourText = "rgr";
if (YourText.Length > 100)
{
    YourText = YourText.Substring(0, 100);
    YourText += "... Read more";
}
```

There are a few issues with the above though, there are lots of refinements you can make but that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Have two Literals or Labels, one of which is hidden with `style="display: none"` (`Visible=False` won't emit the HTML so you can't interact with it from Javascript) and contains the full text.

Your first label/literal ("Read more") needs to have an onclick event that does something like :
`javascript:void(show(LongerText.ClientId));`

`show` and `hide` are defined as:

```
function show(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Set the text of your labels to be a cut down (substring'd) version of the text and the full text.

Should be enough to get you started, but let me know if you need anything more :)

Just to make it extra clear, the structure of the document is this:

Title of document
Read more
hidden text

Comment: Cheers for that your answer was great to and got me started

Comment: Anything in .NET that can tell me when a paragraph is finished or the like ? At the moment using substrings what I am using works fine but i am cutting words half way through

Comment: Look for whitespace.  Say you want 50 characters + however many more it takes to finish the word.  Substring from 50 -> end and then get the first indexOf(" ") (or, better still, a regex character for whitespace that includes tabs and line breaks).  Then you want to substring your original string from 0 to 50+index.